# Questions about help with poorly designed databases

Tags: discussion, questions

If someone asks a question seeking help with a poorly designed, non-normalized data structure, should it be closed?  Just wondering, because even if they get an answer, it's not a *good* answer (unless the answer is, "Start over and normalize your data").

I'm just curious about whether or not that type of question is considered a good addition to SO's stockpile.  If not, what option should be marked as the reason to close?

Example: [Access-VBA Fetch corresponding records from one table write to another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32394269/access-vba-fetch-corresponding-records-from-one-table-write-to-another-table)

Comment: Well, if the question has included everything, that clearly leaves it for being judged _having a poor design_ it can be answered by giving a sample, how to do a better one to fix the problem. It depends on the actual case, if the question is applicable for closure, or may get a useful answer. You should undergird your question with some concrete examples.

Comment: Why would it not be a good answer? There are plenty of poorly designed databases out there and having an answer to help the problem can be useful to others who have a poor database design. If the answer is just start over and normalize your data that provides no real help and is really more of an insulting answer as it is most likely that the person asking the question does not have the authority to make the decision to start over with proper database design.

Answer (score 5):

I think all databases should be normalized to 6NF (wink to [PerformanceDBA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/484814/performancedba)), so I refuse to answer questions about databases that aren't normalized up till that point.

More seriously, legacy and poor design is a thing lots of developers have to handle. You can't always go and normalize mid- or post-project. When following the [guidelines about asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), those questions have their place.